# Chrome html/CSS is not working as expected

Tags: html, css

In Firefox my code works but in Chrome it does not work.

- this is my Chrome result:  [image]
- this is my Firefox result: [image]

```css
.welkom {
  color: #ff0007;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.informatie {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -250px;
  margin-right: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="informatie">
  <p class="welkom">naam: Jasper scheper</p>
  <p class="welkom">leeftijd:15</p>
  <p class="welkom">woonplaats: Nieuw-Buinen</p>
  <p class="welkom">email: placeholder</p>
</div>
```

Comment: because: https://www.google.nl/search?q=negative%20margin%20chrome

Comment: thanks for the answer, but do you know how i can fix it simple?

Comment: Read the answers to the search. There are a few ways

Answer (score 0):

I can see no reason it wouldn't work from the information given, so I can only suggest clearing your browser cache and checking again. Otherwise there may be something deeper in your code going on.

Comment: See the search comment. Chrome does not support negative margin-top. Please get more rep so you can comment instead of posting comments as answers

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: clearing the cache was the fix! thanks for the help and the answer!

Comment: Clearing the cache cannot have been the answer unless you also changed the negative margin

Comment: @mplungjan the negative margin cannot have been the problem because supported in Chrome or otherwise it wouldn't have stopped the font CSS from displaying correctly. Please get more rep so you can answer correctly in future.

Comment: The code as posted by OP does not work in Chrome the way OP wanted it to. It works in FX. Searching for _negative margin chrome_ give solutions posted at SO which all work in Chrome. So there is something with the CSS that fails in Chrome. Clearing my cache does not help on OPs code

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not support negative margin values. To achieve that style you can use `position absolute` on `.informatie` class and adjust the top and right values.

Example:

```
.informatie {
  position:absolute;
  top:300; /* your customised value */
  right:0; /* your customised value */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is u used negative margin value but u can give the element position absolute and the parent relative

```css
.welkom {
  color: #ff0007;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.informatie {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="informatie">
  <p class="welkom">naam: Jasper scheper</p>
  <p class="welkom">leeftijd:15</p>
  <p class="welkom">woonplaats: Nieuw-Buinen</p>
  <p class="welkom">email: placeholder</p>
</div>
```